# Which class invokes base constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, radix

Let's assume we have following classes:

```
class BaseClass
{
   public BaseClass()
   {
      //sth to do
      HERE I WOULD LIKE TO KNOW WHICH CHILD CLASS INVOKES BASE CONSTRUCTOR
   }
}

class ChildClass : BaseClass
{
   public ChildClass() : base() {}
}
```

As described above, I would like to find out in the runtime which child class invoked base class constructor?

Comment: Should `public BaseClass()` be `public ChildClass()`?

Comment: Given `class Base`, `class Derived1 : Base`, `class Derived2 : Derived1`, it will be `Derived1`'s constructor that calls `Base`'s constructor, yet the object will have type `Derived2`. Would you want to see the former or the latter?

Comment: Honestly this sounds like a Bad Idea(TM). The base class should not have to know anything about its inheritors to function correctly. What is the exact problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Would `this.GetType()` suffice? (note: in a multi-level hierarchy, this will always give the concrete type, not the direct sub-type)

Comment: I agree with @lc. This is an XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You have only one child class in your example, but you ask for `which child class`? Any other choice than the only child?

Comment: @KingKing `BaseClass` is not abstract in the question and has a public constructor, so yes, there is another possibility. :)

Answer (score 1):

AS pointed out by @hvd in the comments there are two possible behaviours you could want.

**The actual type of the object**

```
public BaseClass()
{
    Type actualType = this.GetType(); 
    if(actualType == typeof(ChildClass))
    {
        // we are the child class
    }
    else
    {
        // we are not...
    }
}
```

**The constructor that called this constructor**

This is a little harder, but you can examine the calling method if this is just for debug purposes:

```
public BaseClass()
{
    StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
    MethodBase callingMethod = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
    Type callingType = callingMethod.DeclaringType;

    // Then as above, check the type as required
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but be aware it is quite nasty and I would double reconsider using it in production code:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass()
    {
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace();
        string child = st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
        // ...
    }
}
```